# I need to use an SQL query to import data from crsp (within the wrds database) to R

Tags: sql, r

I need to download the returns and volume of trades of all common stock listed in NYSE between 2000 and 2018. When running wrds directly on my R studio I do not know what to write in the SQL query in order to get the returns of all stocks.

I am using dbSendQuery in order to fetch the data I need

```
res <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "select cusip,permno,date,bidlo,askhi
               from crsp.dsf
               where cusip = '...' AND date between '2013-01-07'
               and '2013-01-08'")
data <- dbFetch(res, n=-1)
dbClearResult(res)
data
```

I tried to input 'all' or 'search all' but I got no result

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : 
  Failed to prepare query: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "date"
LINE 3:                    where cusip = 'all' date between '2013-01...
                                               ^
```

Comment: Are you missed `AND` in the `WHERE` clause? I mean `where cusip = 'all' AND date between `

Comment: Yes I actually did, now do I not get an error anymore, but I still get no results from my query

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
res <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "select CUSIP, DATE, PERMNO, PERMCO, PRC, RET, RETX, VOL
                   from CRSP.DSF WHERE DATE >= '2018-03-01' AND DATE < '2018-04-01'")

crsp.dsf <- dbFetch(res, n = -1)
```

Which collects the daily stock prices for one month.